# Azure - How to build a WebJob using a Pipeline coded in a Yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I am totally new to Azure, Pipelines, etc.

I am trying to create an App Service consisting of a web site and a WebJob (a background job that runs periodically). I want to build and deploy it using a Pipeline coded with a Yaml file.

I created a Visual Studio solution with a very simple ASP.Net Core web site (project "pipelines-dotnet-core"), and a simple .Net Core console program (project "WebJobsSDKSample").

I created the Yaml file to build, publish and deploy the web site to my App Service. This works fine and I can open the site in a browser.

I then extended the Yaml file to copy the output folder of the console program project to the publish folder of the web site, compress the result to a zip file and deploy that zip file. I understand that I have to copy the console program project output folder to /App_Data/jobs/triggered/app under the publish folder of the web site.

This new pipeline runs fine, and the web site still gets deployed correctly. However, when I open the WebJobs page of my App Service, it says "You haven't added any WebJobs".

The contents of my Yaml file is below. What do I need to change to correctly deploy the WebJob?

Also, if you could point me at clear examples of how to code a WebJob in a Yaml Pipeline file, that would be really helpful.

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Console App to WebJob Location'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: WebJobsSDKSample/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1
    TargetFolder: pipelines-dotnet-core/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/App_Data/jobs/triggered/app
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive WebApp'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: pipelines-dotnet-core/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: pipelines-dotnet-core/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/pipelines-dotnet-core.zip
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'test connection 1'
    appName: 'WebApplication120200310093243'
    package: pipelines-dotnet-core/bin/Release/**/*.zip
```

Comment: Although this is unrelated to your question, is there a reason you're using a WebJob as opposed to an Azure Function? Well, I suppose it is related since I can actually help you with the YAML for an Azure Function instead of a WebJob :-)